# How does ISO 7816-3 T=0 work?

Tags: smartcard

I'm trying to understand the communication for sending APDU command-response pair. 
Could anyone please explain, in a simple way, how T=0 works?

What are the differences between APDU and TPDU?

For example, the command header is CLA, INS, P1, P2 and P3=0x20 
32 bytes data. how does a card know whether the 5th byte of a command is Lc or Le? 
How does the card know not to expect any command data, and how does it know if the reader is expecting data in the response?

Another thing, when does the procedure byte participate in the scenario? Is it procedure byte? or, procedure bytes? Is it mandatory for the card to send procedure byte?

Comment: Unless you're trying to implement this protocol, this is off-topic for [so]. There are many resourcs on the web that can help you. Google is your friend.

Comment: you should ask one question at a time.

Comment: Although the first comment is correct in principle, I do see that knowledge of this protocol is required to develop against a smart card. I really don't know any other place where this could be asked. There isn't (and probably won't be) a smart card related SE site.

Answer (score 11):

An APDU is an Application Protocol Data Unit, a TPDU a Transport Protocol Data Unit. If an APDU command response pair has been defined for T=0 *and* it has both command data and response data (case 4S) then a separate TPDU will be generated to send and receive data (`GET RESPONSE`). See chapter 12.2.1 of ISO/IEC 7816-3 (2006).

The card knows the meaning of P3 (byte 5) because it is the server. Each command should be implemented in such a way that P3 can only have a single meaning. ISO/IEC 7816 does not comply with the OSI stack in that regard - the layers are not strictly separated. This is one of the **major** issues with ISO 7816.

The procedure byte is part of the T=0 transmission protocol. It is **not** defined in the application protocol, although it may map to SW1, the first part of a status word. It is only send to indicate to the interface device (IFD) what to do. See chapter 10.3.3 of ISO/IEC 7816-3 (2006) for more information. Chapter 10 defines T=0, T=1 does not contain a procedure byte.

Comment: based on https://cardwerk.com/iso-7816-4-annex-a-smart-card-standard/ it looks like long APDUs may get split up into shorter T=0 TPDUs, and perhaps at the transport level then it's clear when the end of an otherwise-unknown APDU instruction has been reached?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use *command / response chaining*, and you could say that defines this spit up of an APDU to TPDU's. From a birds eye view you'll just get separate APDU's though, and in general you may need to split and combine them. Note that there are various implementations possible for this, and I have seen incompatibilities. It is actually kind of hard to handle the memory requirements for command / response chaining. If you would have enough memory for it all then extended length makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

APDU is for Application Layer, TPDU for Physical Layer.
If you  send "00 84 00 00 08" to card, card can response with "xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx 90 00". There is no data behind p3, so p3 stands le. Otherwise, p3 stands lc.
However, I think there is no need to distinguish le and lc.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Communication is divided in 3 parts-
-PC to Controller (Controller have 2 part-A MCU, connected to
Rcontroller unit by i2c or SPI or UART & Radio
Controller Unit).
-Controller to Radio Controller(antenna and Radio Transmission chip)
-Radio Controller to Target or other NFC device.
APDU is from PC to Controller and TPDU is from Controller to Radio Controller.